# del_timer_sync() when the handler re-arms its timer using mod_timer

Tags: timer, linux-kernel

I'm using a periodic timer where the handler function rearms the timer when it is done using mod_timer. When I kill the timer using del_timer_sync() and the handler is running, does this mean that the timer gets re-armed and isn't deleted, or does the function somehow kill the timer? In the case that it doesn't kill the timer, is there a way to know through the return value if the function had to wait for the handler to finish? in that case I can call del_timer_sync() in a loop until the return is not that value. The kernel version I am working with is 2.6.26.5

Answer (score 4):

Looking at how the [`del_timer_sync()`is defined in the Linux kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timer.c#L1066), it will ensure that before it returns, the timer is killed and will not be re-armed.

In other words, `del_timer_sync()` is a blocking function call. When called, if the timer handler is running, `del_timer_sync()` returns only **after** the timer handler completes executing for the last time.